# Maintain precision when averaging floats

Tags: python-2.7, floating-point, floating-accuracy, floating-point-precision, floating-point-conversion

Let's say that I have a large number of floats, e.g. 100, and I need to calculate their average.

To get the most accurate result, should I sum all the numbers and then divide by 100?

Or should I divide each number by 100, and then sum all of them?

(If it matters, I'm coding in Python 2.)

Comment: Those two actions are exactly the same. `(a + b + c)/100` is the same as `a/100 + b/100 + c/100`.

Comment: @MattDMo: In the infinitely precise and accurate world of algebra, yes. As soon as you throw limited precision and accuracy into the mix things start to look a bit different.

Comment: @MattDMo: No, they are not.  Compare the result of summing one hundred 1/100ths (1.0000000000000007) and summing one hundred 1s and then dividing by 100 (1.0).

Comment: @Stephen neither is exactly correct (`0.01`), so how do you pick which one to use?

Comment: @MattDMo: Summing one hundred 1s and dividing by 100 is exactly correct.  In general neither computation is exact, but in this case it is.

Comment: @Stephen you edited your comment. I ran `sum([0.01 for i in range(100)])/100` vs. `sum([0.01/100 for i in range(100)])` and got `0.010000000000000007` and `0.009999999999999995` respectively.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can answer this from a general perspective, rather than a Python perspective.  The answer to your question depends on several factors, including the number of values and the range of the values.

You are correct that adding the numbers together can lead to bad results.  This is called a numerically unstable algorithm.  The problem occurs with floating point arithmetic.  At some point x + 1 = x, because there is no representation for x + 1.

However, you probably don't have to worry about 100 numbers, unless they are quite large.  This issue more typically arises when working with millions of numbers -- or you can get overflow problems with integer arithmetic.

Dividing by the total numbers is not necessarily a solution either, because you can have a problem in the other direction -- too small.

One approach that is more stable is to do an iterative calculation of the averages:

```
avg(1) = x1
avg(2) = avg(1) * (1/2) + x2 * (1/2)
avg(3) = avg(2) * (2/3) + x3 * (1/3)
. . .
avg(n) = avg(n - 1) * ((n - 1) / n) + (x(n) / n)
```

I should note that if your numbers have a very wide range, you can still have problems.  This is also true when you have very large positive and negative numbers that can offset each other.  Other methods may have to be used in this case; these often take into account the size and signs of the numbers.

Comment: If you're concerned about rounding errors from the accumulation, and don't know anything about the distribution of values a priori, it is better to use blocked accumulation (or Kahan summation) than an iterative average calculation.

Answer (score 3):

Sum them and then divide by 100.  A good rule of thumb is that you can usually minimize FP error by performing fewer operations[1].  If you sum them and then divide, you have performed 100 floating-point operations.  If you divide and then sum, you have performed 199 floating-point operations.

[1] there are exceptions where the rounding error of multiple computations exactly cancels out, but this rarely happens by chance -- if this is happening it is usually because an algorithm was designed to work that way by someone who knows what they are doing.

Answer (score 0):

add first then average will get you the most accurate average

If you are interested in accuracy, use [Decimal](https://docs.python.org/2/library/decimal.html)